# PostgreSQL Connection Failover using jdbc string error in Java Application

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, connection, failover

I have a small test application that is making queries towards a Postgresql cluster with a Primary Server (10.200.0.50) and Standby Server (10.200.0.51). When the applcation`s connection to the primary server is not available then I want the application to repoint to the standby.

I followed the last section of documentation from here:
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

So far I have this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Statement stmt = null;
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://10.200.0.50,10.200.0.51:5432/replicationtest",
            "postgres", "password");            

        stmt = c.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM testtable;" );
        while( rs.next() ) {
            String  name = rs.getString("name");
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        rs.close();

        int choice = s.nextInt();

        ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testtable");
        while( rs2.next() ) {
            String  name = rs2.getString("name");
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        rs2.close();
        c.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    s.close();
}
```

Scenario A) Primary server 10.200.0.50 is Down and Standby server
    10.200.0.51 is Up.

This works great, there is a little delay at first but then the application uses the second server specified in the jdbc string

Scenario B) Both Primary and Standby servers are up when I run the application. But after the first query, where the application is waiting on nextInt(), I block the connection to 10.200.0.50; Simulating the primary failing after a connection has been successfully made.

When I run scenario B and then invoke the second query I get the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:317)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:432)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:358)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:305)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:291)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:269)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:236)
at com.rakuten.pgRecovery.Main.main(Main.java:59)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I need to wrap my queries in a try catch and catch the error when the read fails. After that I need to open a new connection which will do round robin on the passed nodes and thus a get a good connection, like in Scenario A